# I'm having an 2D Array Redefinition Error

Tags: c++, arrays, redefinition

There is an error (actually 3 same errors) with my definition array `int mang[max][max]` and I couldn't find anything to fix it properly, so I hope someone will notice my question and help me soon. XD

In my header `file array.h`, I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#define max 100
using namespace std;
int mang[max][max];

void NhapMang(int mang[][max], int hang, int cot); 
void XuatMang(int mang[][max], int hang, int cot);
int TinhTongPhanTu(int mang[][max], int hang, int cot);
int DemPhanTux(int mang[][max], int hang, int cot);
```

When I was typing my code, VS shows me that there is "no issues found" all over .cpp files, but when I debug the code, the error appears in the header file `array.h`, says "C2086 'int mang[100][100]': redefinition" altogether.
I think that I've defined *mang* twice or more, but I couldn't find the other *mang* definition nor fixing it if I found. [This is the capture of the error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKXBv.png).
I don't know what parts I need provide to you in my project to help fixing it for me (and I also think my post would become so long to read if I copy-paste all my code up here :-( ), so if you need any further information, just comment and I will give it to you.

And well, I've just start learning C++ for 3 months, so there's soooo many things I haven't known yet XD If there's anything I couldn't understand in the way you fix the problem, please let me ask you more about it.

Hope you understand what I mean XD (cuz I'm not a native speaker). And thank you for reading.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Presumbly `array.h` is `#include`'d by multiple implementation files and you then link the resulting object files together, right? Hint: there is nothing wrong with any one file (which is why the linter isn't complaining), there is something wrong with the way you use several file together.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is that the pre-processor is a text altering engine. In every file where you have `#include "array.h"`, the *textual contents* of `array.h` are inserted in place of the `#include`.

So, if you have several files that include `array.h` then each one of those files declares and defines `mang` (all using the same definition). That isn't a problem during compilation because each file is compiled separately, but they each generate an object file that defines `mang`.

Then you try to link, and the linker sees several defitions of the array.

The solution is the same as the one you are using for *functions* in `array.h`: you *declare* in the header and *define* in the implementation (presumably `array.cpp`).

How do you declare an array without defining it?

Good question. I'm glad you asked. You do it with the `extern` keyword like this.

`array.h`:

```
// ...
#define max 100
extern int mang[max][max];      // <=== Look here (with extern)
// ...
```

Then you define it in `array.cpp`:

```
// ...
int mang[max][max];      // <== and compare to this (no extern)
// ..
```

---

As an aside you using the pre-processor to define constants (like `#define max 100` has several downsides, and in c++ you are generally better off using compile-time constants like

```
const int max = 100;  // Pre c++11
```

or

```
constexpr int max = 100; // c++11 or later
```

(The use of the pre-processor for this is a holdover from ancient days when compilers were a lot less clever.)

Answer (score 2):

The language rules say:

> [basic.def.odr]
>
> Every program shall contain **exactly one** definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement; no diagnostic required. ...

(There are some exceptions with limitations that are listed in further rules, but none that apply to your example)

---

> ```
> int mang[max][max];
> ```

This is definition of a variable. That definition is in a header file. Header files are typically *included* into multiple translation units. If you do so, then you have *included* the definition of the variable into multiple translation units. By having multiple definitions of a non-inline variable, you would violate the rule quoted above.